# want to make overflow y hidden when loader is true but overflow y hidden not doing anything

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow

Despite adding a pre-loader to my website to wait for API calls to load before displaying the content, I have encountered an issue where the overflow-y: hidden property is not functioning as expected. This means that I am still able to scroll on the website even though I have explicitly set the overflow-y property to "hidden".

```js
import './App.css';
import Upcoming from './sections/Upcoming';
import Hero from './sections/Hero';
import Ranking from './sections/Ranking';
import Live from './sections/Live';
import Ended from './sections/Ended';
import Loader from './components/Loader';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [loader, setLoader]=useState(true)

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoader(false);
    }, 6000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={`${loader?'overflow-y-hidden':''}`} >

        {loader && <Loader/>}

        <Hero s={open} />
        <Live s={open}/>
        <div className='w-[calc(100vw-20px)] h-[1px] bg-[#4776d5] rounded-[10px] ml-[20px] mt-[20px] mb-[20px]' />
        <Ended s={open}/>
        <div className='w-[calc(100vw-20px)] h-[1px] bg-[#4776d5] rounded-[10px] ml-[20px] mt-[20px] mb-[20px]' />

        <Ranking/>
        <div className='w-[calc(100vw-20px)] h-[1px] bg-[#4776d5] rounded-[20px] ml-[20px] mt-[20px] mb-[20px]' />

        <Upcoming/>

      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS?